# Simple JQuery POST not even working

Tags: php, jquery, post

Okay, so I'm pretty new at JQuery, but regardless, this seems like a simple enough thing to do.

I'm working on a "cart" of sorts, where the items are stored locally and then sent via jquery.post to a mail script.

Now, for some reason my code isn't doing anything, and I don't know why, because it's code that's plain and simple. I've replaced my cart variable to simple text to test it, because I thought that my data might be the actual culprit.

```
$(".order-cart").click(function() {
    $current_cart = "test";
    $.post('../thank-you.php', {cart_items:$current_cart}, function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've tested the button, works fine. But it's still not doing anything at all...why is this not working? What am I missing? I've also tested it on a server, both WAMP and online.

PHP is just this:

```
<?php
$cart_items = $_POST["cart_items"];
echo $cart_items;
?>
```

Thanks so much!

```
Edit:
After playing around with it a bit, I noticed the following error in the console (using Chrome)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Design/Assault%20Ou%20Studios/Clients/Client%20Work/2Dive4%20Scuba/Website/thank-you.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Your code is correct and should work - do you get any JS error? But why do you prefix your variables with `$`?

Comment: Debug it, open the network tab of the browser and check the request, you have put the code within document ready handler, right?

Comment: Hi @ThiefMaster, not getting any errors, and I've tested it in Safari, Chrome, FireFox and IE. That said, I just prefix my variables out of habbit!

Comment: @undefined Yup, all wrapped in a ready handler.

Comment: @VernonJoyce, are you running this locally? same domain origin policy means you cant use ajax or json for files out side of your domainname.. ie if i had google.com all the files i want to ajax or json in would have to reside on google.com im not sure how it works locally but it might be out of your "folder-sytem" and you MUST  be running a webserver to serve php files

Answer (score 0):

Try initialize your variable like this:

```
$(".order-cart").click(function() {
    var current_cart = "test";
    $.post('../thank-you.php', {cart_items: current_cart}, function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: While that makes the code better it is only required when he's in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: @ThiefMaster well, let see how, I can't see any more problem with his code though

Comment: user, i agree.  @Vernon Joyce use chrome and use the console to make sure you have no linking errors.

Comment: @user1479606 Didn't change much I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dnaso I don't have any linking errors, but I've updated the question with something that I have no come across.

Comment: @VernonJoyce The file needs to be placed on a webserver and then executed. Normally browers don't allow file:/// protocol for AJAX calls for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me!
Put this in new file and test it

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<input type='button' class='order-cart' value='click me'>
<script>
$(".order-cart").click(function() {
    $current_cart = "test";
    $.post('../thank-you.php', {cart_items:$current_cart}, function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Also are your sure that your "thank-you.php" file location is correct?

Comment: Hi there, the php file is definitely in the right location, because I tried linking to it directly too as I thought initially that this might be the suspect. Only thing I can think of is that another piece of the JQuery might be interfering, but not too sure.

Comment: @VernonJoyce Try to debug your script with f12 (if you are using google chrome) and checkout "console"

Answer (score 0):

Your script is correct!!!!
Your **"thank-you.php"** file location is incorrect!!!